# Removing stopwords from text corpus using linux commandline

Tags: macos, sed

I have about 200MB of text file (rawtext.txt) and have a list of stop words in a text file (stopwords.txt).

```
I
a
about
an
are
as
at
be
by
com
for
```

...

I want to remove the stopwords in the text corpus. But how? What is the fastest and easiest way? Prefer a command line like sed or tr. Dont want to use python or NLTK.

Can somebody help? I am using Mac OSX (not linux)

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input to word-per-line format, and you can filter it with `grep`:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < rawtext.txt | fgrep -vwf stopwords.txt
```

This way you don't have to build an arbitrarily large regexp, which could be a problem if your stopwords list is large.

Comment: Converting a large text input (GB of data) into one word per line is not feasible.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be feasible? You don't need to store it in that form, it's done by the `tr` call in the first half of the pipeline. Did you try it? (In case it's not clear: `rawtext.txt` is your original file; it's changed into word-per-line by `tr`, and filtered with `fgrep`.)

Comment: Hey. I ran this command but stop words removal not working. :( All i need to do replace such stopwords with a blank space.

Comment: Well, I tested it and it worked for me, so you'll have to help yourself a little: Does the `tr` command do what it should? Test it on a short file and inspect the output. If not, check the manual and see if `tr` accepts the `:blank:` character class (if not, try your luck with `tr -s ' ' '\n'`).

Comment: It worked for you in linux? I am using Mac OSX. It didnt work for me with mac terminal

Comment: I'm on OS X Mountain Lion. If you want more help from me, you're going to have to do better than "it didn't work for me." You can start with my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution (also in Mac OS):

```
cat rawtext.txt | grep -o -E '[a-zA-Z]{3,}' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq | grep -vwFf stopwords.txt
```

This would extract just the 3-letter words (without numbers), convert to lowercase, sort and get uniques, then filter with the stop words.

Make sure stopwords.txt was treated in the same way (e.g. lowercase).

Comment: Damn, this would have worked for me but I don't want to remove duplicate non-stopwords.